# Is this Sigma Protocol zero knowledge or is it just a proof of knowledge?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, provable-security, sigma-protocol

Suppose I have the witness $x$ and need to prove that I correctly computed $(g^x)^x$ to a verifier. $g$ and $g^x$ are public. The verifier asks me for $(g^x)^x$, but wants proof that I've given them the right answer.

Here's my attempt at a solution:

Let $X = g^x$ and $X' = (g^x)^x$

Step 1: Prover chooses a random $r$ and sends $R = g^r$ and $R' = X^r$

Step 2: Verifier sends a random $c$ (challenge)

Step 3: Prover sends $z = r + cx$ (response)

Step 4: Verifier checks if $g^z = RX^c$ and $X^z = R'(X')^c$.

I was wondering whether this is zero knowledge or just a proof of knowledge.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess that it's also zero-knowledge, but I'll let you do the proof. However, an easier thing to note is that if $X=g^x$ and $X'=g^{x^2}$ then it follows that $(g,X,X,X')$ is a Diffie-Hellman tuple (i.e., it is of the form $(g,g^a,g^b,g^{ab})$. As such, you could use the standard Diffie-Hellman tuple Sigma protocol as a "black box".

(Note that Sigma protocols are defined as honest-verifier zero-knowledge, so that is the level we are aiming for here.)

Comment: More precisely, it's honest-verifier zero-knowledge.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau You are absolutely right, but this is the level of zero knowledge required for Sigma protocols, so I didn't clarify that. But, indeed, this should be stated so I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simulator $S$ might work as follows: it generates a random $(c,z)$ and calculates $R=g^{z}X^{-c}$ and $R^{'}=X^{z}(X^{'})^{-c}$. Clearly, $((R,R^{'}),c,z)$ have the same distribution as in a real run. Namely, random values
satisfying $g^{z}=RX^{c}$ and $X^{z}=R^{'}(X^{'})^{c}$.